# Como agregar elementos marcados a un checklistbox y como eliminarlos

Tags: c#, windows-forms

El objetivo es que en un cheboxlistbox se añadan los elementos de un textbox, estos aparezcan marcados y luego pueda seleccionar y borrar estos elementos del checboxlistbox. En el checklistbox debo de añadir elementos a la lista, y que al añadirlos aparezcan marcados y a parte poder seleccionar elementos de la lista y borrar el elemento seleccionado. en la imagen sería los elementos de la parte inferior izquierda.
Este es el código de añadir elementos al checklistbox

```
private void btañadir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtañadir.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ha de rellenar el formulario.");

        }
        else
        {
            clbidiomas.Items.Add(txtañadir);

            MessageBox.Show("Los datos se han añadido correctamente.");
        }
    }
```

y este es el codigo de borrar(en el cual no he implementado nada)

```
private void btborrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias ser mas claro? muchoooooooo mas claro.. queres hacer que cosas? y agrega esa info en la pregunta por favor.

Comment: Te comento, en el checklistbox debo de añadir elementos a la lista, y que al añadirlos aparezcan marcados y a parte poder seleccionar elementos de la lista y borrar el elemento seleccionado. en la imagen sería los elementos de la parte inferior izquierda.

Comment: perfecto. esa explicacion debe estar en la pregunta. Por lo que veo en tu codigo, solamente agregaste items al checkbox.. que otras cosas probaste?? agrega toda la info a la pregunta usando el boton [edit]

Comment: Tengo la misma duda que usted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El metodo add, que usas correctamente, devuelve el indice del item que acabas de agregar.

Por lo tanto, con unos pequeños cambios, puedes marcar el item que acabas de agregar:

```
int index = clbidiomas.Items.Add(txtañadir);
clbidiomas.SetItemChecked(index, true);
```

El metodo SetItemChecked, setea el item ubicado en index, con el valor que vos le digas (en este caso a true, o sea marcado)

Para eliminar un item de la lista, se usa `.Items.RemoveAt` si sabes el indice a remover.

Si no, por ejemplo si quisieras remover todos lo que estan marcados, debes recorrer la coleccion interna que dice cuales estan marcados e ir quitandolos.

```
while (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
{
     checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[0]);
}
```